# Behaviour of a spectral measure - question regarding certain terms used to describe its behaviour

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, spectral-theory

Good morning,

I'd like to ask a question based on [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.00204.pdf) paper, which is about Gaussian Stationary Processes.
One of the main concepts is the concept of a spectral measure. After Theorem 4.1 of this paper is proven, there is a behaviour of the spectral measure described as being "exploding at $0$" if $\gamma <1$ (the assumption is, that $\rho ([0, \frac{1}{N}]) \geq bN^{-\gamma}$, where $\rho$ is the spectral measure). Similarly, a spectrum bounded at $0$ is considered to be for $\gamma =1$ and a spectrum vanishing at $0$ is considered to be for $\gamma >1$.

Can someone explain to me this terminology? I am familiar to the terms in this paper and the other steps made there are clear.